# What does thread of continuity mean when describing an entity in Domain Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design, entity

Eric Evans defines an Entity as "an object fundamentally defined not by its attributes, but by a thread of continuity and identity". Does thread of continuity imply that entities must be stored to a database in order to outlive the application?

Comment: Great power of internet has thought pattern ao close, I also had same query while reading DDD

Answer (score 1):

In general entities are stored somewhere and primarily they are retrieved through repositories.

However, what Evan means that entity must have its identity and continuity in the modeled world.  I could imaging a situation when entity comes from outside of your application and then goes somewhere else and you can even skip database, but it remains entity  while you can identify it next time it comes.  Other entities may still refer to it by holding its id.

Answer (score 1):

What is it of an entity that remains stable/unchanged/present over the course of its life cycle? Its identity. The rest of its attributes can change. Even after its life has ended we should be able to reference it providing proper contextual information (e.g. include a date or a period). This is in high contrast to value objects which are fundamentally defined by their properties, lack identity and are not referenced. Common value objects are color (rgb values), money (amount + currency), weight (amount + unit), age (expressed in years, months, days), <insert_the_ones_from_your_domain_here>, ... Touch any of that internal state and it's not the same thing anymore.

Comment: Thanks, but does it imply persisting entities in database?

Comment: A thread of continuity, AFAIK, pertains to an entity's life-cycle and the fact it 'goes through the moves', i.e. changes state throughout its life-cycle. How that state gets persisted is besides the point (database, memory, who cares). I don't couple it with the notion of persistence, but I'd say 99% of the time, entities get persisted.

Answer (score 0):

An object that is associated with a unique identifier. Its attributes may change but not the identifier itself that represents that object.